# Ember data "Assertion Failed: Attributes must be numbers, [...], not function (data) { return template [...]"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this error from time to time when I transition from one route to another :

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attributes must be numbers, strings or booleans, not function (data) {
  return template
    .replace(/\{\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
      // tripple curlies -> no-escaping
      return get(data, match);
    }).replace(/\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
     return escapeExpression( get(data, match) );
    });
}
```

I'm using `"ember-cli": "0.2.5"`, `"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.19"` and `"ember": "1.12.0"`.

I don't have a clue where that could come from, any lead please ?

Comment: Looks like `ember-data` error. Could you post your model definition, please.

Comment: Thanks, It's an ember-data error I guess too. I have several models (too much to paste here), all attributes are of types 'string', 'number',  'boolean' or 'date'. Nothing fancy.

Comment: The code you show is from model property?

Comment: It's not code, it's just the full error displayed in chrome console. I have found something funny if you google for "tripple curlies -> no-escaping" : https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/issues/194
I do use ember-i18n ! However I don't understand what possible relation could be between ember-data and ember-i18n !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Ember Handlebars template error.
I guess you have computed property that doesn't properly defined and used in template.

By "not properly defined" I mean you might forget to add `}.property()` at the end

```
// as is you have something like this
qwerty: function {
  // some code
}

// to be
qwerty: function {
  // some code
}.property(),

// or 
qwerty: Ember.computed(function {
  // some code
}),
```

Sorry, if my guess is wrong.

Comment: That's an idea, thanks, I'll dig into that and let you know ! :)